# httpUrlConnection shows me not authorized java

Tags: java, authorization, httpurlconnection

slt,
I have developed the following code to connect to a website. despite, I've put authentication code, it shows 401 not authorized. the code is below:
any idea please!

```
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
            //con.connect();
            String username="admin";
            String password="pwd";
            String userpass=username+":"+password;
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does it shows "401 not authorized?".

The server remembers that you are logged in by assigning you a sessionID, when you enter your username and password. In webbrowsers this sessionID is stored in a cookie and you have to send that cookie each time you send a message to the server in order to stay logged in.

Comment: I'm sorry! I didn't understand what do you mean.
it shows 401 in client side.